Avoid cross talk between recording electrodes
I am trying to compare two record signals coming from two INA amplifiers simultaneously. Both amplifiers are actually recording the same signal, just with different recording electrodes. We are interested in the performance comparison of the two electrode types. We are aware of input current biasing and have designed our circuitry thus far in the manner as shown below. However, the two different recording electrode types (WE vs RE) sit naturally at quite a high DC potential difference between each other. Meaning, WE electrodes in solution might be 500-1000 mV above the RE-electrodes in solution due to their Nernst potentials in our recording medium. Note: Both electrode types (Types: WE and RE, 2 each) are in the same solution at the same time.
The circuit below records... the problem is, we do not want a leakage current path connecting the WE electrodes to the RE electrodes, as this is essentially forming a battery between the two. With lower resistor values, we even saw corrosion of one recording electrode and deposition onto the other electrode type. Note: The 10M ohm resistors connecting to AGND are needed to bias the amplifiers to common mode input, but they also create a 20M ohm path between the various electrode types where roughly 100nA of current flows, killing the low leakage current feature of the INAs.
Are there any ideas on how to avoid this or go around this?
Edit for more information:
This is only a snapshot of the analog front end of the board. The power comes from an external supply and is converted to the required voltage supplies (iso+, iso-, AGND) with an isolating DC/DC converter.These power rails are common to the entire analog end.
The outputs of the INAs go to an ADC which then heads to an isolated SPI comms to communicate back to the rest of the system on Digital Ground. The electrodes are different metal types in various conducting solutions and/or acids. One could picture here ion/chemical sensing through potential measurements.



Welcome! There's some details regarding the power supply that might be helpful and might be worth clarifying either with a clear description or in schematic form. Just to confirm, does iso+ and iso- mean that you have one supply, isolated, that both op amps are sharing? Is that supply referenced to AGND?

The circuit below records <-- no it does not record; it's an amplifier/buffer. Maybe there's some translation thing going on? What would a battery form between the two electrodes. This is unclear. What sort of cruel environment is this located in and finally, what signal are you recording and why do you have two channels? Your schematic node names imply they are connected at the power supplies. You need to be much clearer about this and, be specific in your question because it's not clear.

what actually are the sensors, and what environment are they in? context is everything. When describing a problem please remember that the other party does not have the contextual information that you do.

Thank you all for your comments, I edited the original post to try and address these.


What would be the maximum leakage current between the two sets of electrodes that will give acceptable results?  2. Regarding the voltage signals  being measured, what is the min & max expected amplitude range, & frequency range? 3. Regarding the conducting fluid, what is its temperature range?


We want less than nanoamperes to flow. Ideally femto or picoampere scale, such as listed for these INAs. The voltage scale is +/-10mV with effectively DC signals. The temperature remains mostly the same at 5-10 degrees celsius.

Is AGND connected to the medium through any paths other than the ion membrane (assuming, my chem is shaky) in the four electrodes shown? i.e. any other salt bridges, direct metallic/ohmic connections, conductive vessel attached to that ground, etc? Additionally, is it economical to simply duplicate the ADCs and isolated supplies so your two frontends are isolated independently with independent analog grounds and power rails?

"Meaning, WE electrodes in solution might be 500-1000 mV above the RE-electrodes ".  Comment: assuming 1V between these electrodes, for 1nA of current the minimum resistance between these electrode pairs must be greater than 1GΩ.  This will be challenging to achieve.

Question 4. With no external circuit connected to the electrode pairs (ie: no amplifiers connected), what is the common-mode voltage between the two electrode pairs when placed in the conducting fluid?  This will need to be measured with a precision volt meter having an impedance of more than 1Gohm, ie: not your common garden variety DMM with 10Mohm impedance.

Question 5:  With no external circuit connected to the electrode pairs (ie: no amplifiers connected), how much current do you expect to flow between the electrode pairs in the conductive fluid?  (I am trying to work out how much of the corrosion problem is a natural part of the process & sensor set-up, and how much is due to the influence of the current flow in the external circuit, the amplifier).

@nanofarad  Having independent isolated grounds for each front end amplifier circuit is something I had considered and am working on designing. My hesitancy here is the concept of the amplifiers being truly isolated from each other... as each ground will then still be connected to the solution via the electrodes. Its a solution that i think will help, but I also can't fully explain why it will help.
We also have the option of putting the AGND into solution via an external electrode, which we have tried. It helps sometimes, but is heavily dependent upon the electrode impedence in solution.

@Potatoconomy: based on your last comment here, I would suggest having four (4) independent amplifiers that are each isolated from any ground node and from each other.   The isolation voltage is not very high (below a few volts), but the parasitic impedance to any common node needs to be very high (over 1Gohm, well over 100 times what you have now).   Connect each of these amplifiers to one of the electrodes.
The output of these amplifiers can then be connected to a signal processing stage that is ground referenced.

It may be possible to avoid having fully galvanically isolated amplifiers provided that the voltages of all four electrodes lie within the span of the power supply rails of these four amplifiers at all times.  This is practical if the op-amp power supply rails are, say, +12V and -12V, and the electrode voltages never exceed, say, +5V or -5V wrt to the 0V of the opamp power supplies.  You can connect the conducting fluid to this 0V if that helps - beware that liquid moving within a pipe may generate electric potentials due to friction.


Note: The 10M ohm resistors connecting to AGND are needed to bias the amplifiers to common mode input, but they also create a 20M ohm path between the various electrode types where roughly 100nA of current flows, killing the low leakage current feature of the INAs.

There should be no need to put these 10MΩ resistors from each electrode to the circuit GND to bias the amplifiers to common mode.  The solution is to remove these resistors, and find an alternative way to achieve the same outcome.
The solution should be simple: connect the conducting fluid to the AGND of your circuit, and ensure the power rails of the op-amps (INAs) have sufficient range (both positive and negative) to keep all electrode voltages within the INA121 common-mode range at all times.  The datasheet of the INA121 states that the maximum supply voltage is 36V, so you could apply power supply rails of, for example, +12V & -12V, or as high as +/-18V; from what you have described, however, it would seem +/-5V should be sufficient.
The schematic below shows this idea;  the connection to the conducting fluid could be via a different electrode, or perhaps to the container or pipe, provided it is sufficiently conductive.
Note that I did not have a model of the INA121, the closest I could find in the standard LTspice library is the AD SSM2141, the schematic does not show the feedback components.


The app note associated with the INA121 may be quite relevant.
SBOA503,
Importance of Input Bias Current Return Paths in Instrumentation Amplifier
Applications

Thanks Fabio, I will try this next week and report back here what happens.

Excellent, looking forward to seeing your results.  Note that the value of R2 is rather arbitrary here; it can probably be reduced to zero, however, leaving it as 10k may be useful as a means of measuring the current flowing into the conducting fluid from the ground connection.

Thanks Fabio for your input. I removed the resistors connecting the non-inverting inputs to AGND and simply connected AGND with a physical electrode (I did forget the R2 10k resistor but that can be done later). Doing this immediately allowed me to read values that mostly agreed with other high impedance voltmeters from the electrodes. I say mostly agreed, because depending on the electrode type used for this connection, a different DC bias (on the scale of 0.5-1 mV) was introduced in the amplifier/ADC read out.

Excellent news.  If you have high-impedance volt meters to measure the electrode voltages independently, then it would be interesting to plot the reported difference voltage WE_out (& RE_out) vs the common-mode voltage at the INA121 inputs (the average of the two voltages at WE_1 & WE_2).  Ideally, if WE_1 & WE_2 are connected together, & connected to a node with an adjustable voltage (lets call this voltage Vcm), then WE_out should remain at 0mV while Vcm remains within the common-mode range of the INA121 (which is stated on the datasheet).
